# How to update value in multiple documents searching by id's in PyMongo MongoDB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to update multiple documents searching by id's
I already tried like this:

```
users = await user_collection.update_many(
    {"_id": {"$in": users_id}}, {"$push": {
                    "assigned_buildings": building_id
                }}
```

MongoDB returns ok but none of documents are updated.

When I'm adding ObjectId:

```
users = await user_collection.update_many(
    {"_id": {"$in": ObjectId(users_id)}}, {"$push": {
                    "assigned_buildings": building_id
                }}
)
```

MongoDB returns id must be an instance of (bytes, str, ObjectId), not <class 'list'>

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I made it like this but I'm still looking for more sophisticated way:

```
updated_users_id = []
for user_id in users_id:
    updated_users_id.append(ObjectId(user_id))

users = await user_collection.update_many(
    {"_id": {"$in": updated_users_id}}, {"$push": {
                    "assigned_buildings": building_id
                }}
)
```

Comment: That should be the legit way to achieve what you want. In your original question, you are trying to put a list inside an objectId. Instead, you should create a list of ObjectId s, which is what you are doing now.